# Process task to execute a batch script runs forever

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, ssis

I have a simple batch script that should be trigger by the SSIS process task. 
Process Task setting:
**Executable** value is set from an expression.
**Window:** Hidden.
**Rest are default values.**

When I execute it manually, I get this pop up-
Windows Pop up message that says"**We can't verify who created this file.Are you sure you want to run?**
Choosing 'Run' makes the script execute without a glitch.

I deployed this package and scheduled a job on SSMS. However, I noticed the job executes forever. At this stage, I set up logging in SSIS package. I compared the log from manual run v/s job run. The job went into this 'forever' mode at the same step when pop up had appeared during manual run. 
**id    event**
96  OnPostValidate
97  OnPostValidate
98  PackageStart
99  Diagnostic
100 OnPreExecute
101 OnPreExecute
102 OnPostValidate
103 OnProgress  --- Job run gets stuck at this stage

All the access rights are in place for the proxy account that runs the job. Absolute paths have been used in the script and SSIS variables.

I have spent a lot of hours on this. Appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to run it as a shell command inside a script task?

Comment: @Ako It is another developer that made this script. I have no knowledge about this!ECHO OFF 
"C:\Program Files\QlikView\QMSEDX_CommandLine\qmsedx.exe" -task="CALs" -qms=xxxx -password=xxxxx > "D:\SSIS\QVBatchScript\EDX_error.log"
EXIT /B

Comment: You could call the same batch inside a scripting task and writing this code: 
            Interaction.Shell(@"d:\myscript.cmd", AppWinStyle.Hide, true);

Comment: I have spent hours and hours on this now. Could you please explain what is the difference between your script and his? Just for my understanding. Of course, I will try your snippet right away. trigger_QV_Update.bat is the file name with the above code. Is myscript.cmd =trigger_QV_UPdate.cmd in my case?

Comment: So this a more lower level approach that should prevent waiting for the pop-up. You can also specify a timeout when you want to stop waiting.

Comment: I assume that you want to execute Interaction.Shell(@"d:\trigger_QV_UPdate.bat", AppWinStyle.Hide, true); depending on the path of the batch file